# How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectively?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do IN() queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate. Currently I do something like that:

```
StringBuilder jobTypeInClauseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < jobTypes.length; i++) {
    Type jobType = jobTypes[i];

    if(i != 0) {
        jobTypeInClauseBuilder.append(',');
    }

    jobTypeInClauseBuilder.append(jobType.convert());
}
```

Which is quite painful since if I have nine lines just for building the clause for the IN() query. I would like to have something like the parameter substitution of prepared statements

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You want a parameter source:

```
Set<Integer> ids = ...;

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", ids);

List<Foo> foo = getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a IN (:ids)",
     parameters, getRowMapper());
```

This only works if `getJdbcTemplate()` returns an instance of type [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html)

Comment: Perfect, the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate was exactly what i was looking for. Additionally i like named parameters more than those question marks all over the place. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This works for small lists, but attempting to use it on a large list results in a query where :ids is replaced with "?,?,?,?,?......" and with enough list items it overflows. Is there a solution that works for large lists?

Comment: You should probably insert the values into a temporary table and build the condition using `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: To comlete answer: [Spring 3.1 Reference — Passing in lists of values for IN clause](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause). But in Reference was nothing said about: [it is possible to pass any Collection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.jdbc/3.0.6/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterUtils.java/#206).

Comment: strange, i get "error code [17004]; Invalid column type" when I try this.

Comment: @yawn Is it possible to return a `Map<String,List<Objects>>` for `List<Foo>` as in your answer . my [Question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405095/using-a-query-inside-rowmapper)

Comment: With SQLServer, large lists can cause an Exception.  "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request."

Comment: I had spent several hours working towards a solution, toggling my code back and forth between the traditional JdbcTemplate and the Parameterized Jdbc Template.  I like this solution because the Java Set Collection guarantees built in uniqueness of the ID keys being added.  It also beats manually building a String representing a comma separated series of ID's.  Thank you!

Comment: What will happen if ids is empty here?

Comment: @manikantanvsr hey there, i tried running the query with an empty list & an error is thrown. your query will look like `SELCET * FROM TABLE WHERE id IN ()`. You can refer to https://rzymek.github.io/post/jpa-empty-in/ for possible solutions

Answer (score 69):

I do the "in clause" query with spring jdbc like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT bg.goodsid FROM beiker_goods bg WHERE bg.goodsid IN (:goodsid)";

List ids = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{12496,12497,12498,12499});
Map<String, List> paramMap = Collections.singletonMap("goodsid", ids);
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = 
    new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());

List<Long> list = template.queryForList(sql, paramMap, Long.class);
```

Comment: You just posted an answer to a almost three year old question with the same solution as the accepted answer had. Is there any good reason behind this? :-)

Comment: This answer provides more clarity because it illustrates that the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is needed for this API... so thanks for the additional detail janwen

Comment: @janwen , Thanks for the solution!!! It's working fine as per my requirement!!

Comment: This solution worked for me when the array of IDs was very large.  The accepted answer's solution fails when the array is too large.

Answer (score 20):

If you get  an exception for : Invalid column type

Please use `getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()` instead of `getJdbcTemplate()`

```
 List<Foo> foo = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a IN (:ids)",parameters,
 getRowMapper());
```

Note that the second two arguments are swapped around.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to this question. Should it be a comment on another answer?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Two years later,  it definitely warrants being an answer.

Comment: getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() is undefined. need to extend NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport if you want that method.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181219121911/http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/76237-jdbccursoritemreader-with-named-parameters)

write query with named parameter, use simple `ListPreparedStatementSetter` with all parameters in sequence. Just add below snippet to convert the query in traditional form based to available parameters,

```java
ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(namedSql);

List<Integer> parameters = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (A a : paramBeans)
    parameters.add(a.getId());

MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("placeholder1", parameters);
// create SQL with ?'s
String sql = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, parameterSource);     
return sql;
```

Comment: for me this was the only answer that worked as I just wanted to set few placeholders

Answer (score -3):

Many things changed since 2009, but I can only find answers saying you need to use NamedParametersJDBCTemplate.

For me it works if I just do a

```
db.query(sql, new MyRowMapper(), StringUtils.join(listeParamsForInClause, ","));
```

using SimpleJDBCTemplate or JDBCTemplate

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the content in `listeParamsForInClause` wont be escaped and makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.