# How to generate a dynamic "in (...)" sql list through Spring JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring

Is it possible to generate arbitrary "in ()" lists in a SQL query through Jdbc template:

example:

"select * from t where c in (#)" , However '#' could be an arbitrary list of values only known at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in Spring if you use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` or `SimpleJdbcTemplate` with named parameters. List parameter can be set as a `java.util.List`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");

List<SomeObject> result = simpleJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM t WHERE c in (:list)",
    new RowMapper<SomeObject>() { ... },
    Collections.singletonMap("list", list));
```

In this case Spring internally creates the SQL query with the required number of placeholders based on the size of the actual list when replacing named parameters with `?`s.

Comment: This does nt work if your IN(...) arguments are not Strings (text). For example if you wanna pass a List<Long> this way, you'll get Wrong data type: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[2, 3, 4]"

Comment: @ShivanDragon Is there a correct way to do it in that case?

General note on the original answer. With java 8 you can use the lambda format `(rs, rowNum) -> {...}` in place of `new RowMapper<SomeObject>() { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate , you can use following sample:

```
if(tenors != null && tenors.length >0)
            sql.append(" and ip.tenor_id in (:tenors)");

.....


if(tenors != null && tenors.length >0){
    query.setParameterList("tenors", tenors);                                 
}
.....
SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString())
```

Comment: The question was not about Hibernate but rather Spting JDBC template

Answer (score 0):

SimpleJDBCTemplate is depricated now. You can use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate instead. 
Sample code is below.
If you have multiple parameters of different kind you can 
use `Object` as key, otherwise use your `List<T>`

```
String sqlAllEmpl = queryLoader.getProperty("allEmployeesByLevelAndPeriod");
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paramMap.put("level", levelStr);
        paramMap.put("periodList", periodList);

        gridList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sqlAllEmpl, paramMap, new YourRowMapper());
```

your sqlAllEmpl  will have two place holders, `level` - string and `periodList` - which is a list used in the IN statement of sql.