# Using "where in" in spring-jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Is there a way to delete a bunch of elements using "where... in" in SQL, like so:

```
HashSet<String> idStrings = ...;
SimpleJdbcTemplate template = getTemplate();
template.update("DELETE FROM records WHERE idstring IN (?)", idStrings);
```

I am trying to get some old code to work that uses this method, but whenever I try to run it the Oracle JDBC drivers throw an exception:

> QL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

This is with ojdbc5 11.2.0.1.0 and spring-jdbc 3.0.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a dynamic "in (...)" sql list through Spring JdbcTemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you need one placeholder (`?`) per ID, and each ID must be bound separately.

You could also use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html), which

> [...] also allows for expanding a List of values to the appropriate number
>   of placeholders.

Be careful not to put too many values in the set of IDs. Oracle limits them to 1000, for example.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I got a java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type.  Any ideas?