# BeanPropertySqlParameterSource to insert list of values

Tags: java, spring

If a bean has list field , how can I use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to insert the list of values to database using BeanPropertySqlParameterSource? If it's not possible then what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way since there is no direct way to map a list of values to one column.  There are any number of things you may be wanting it to do.  This is about the closest option.

[How to generate a dynamic "in (...)" sql list through Spring JdbcTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate)

`String query = "select * from table where columnName in (:listOfValues)";
    List nameRecordIDs = new ArrayList(); 
    // ...
    // add values to collection, then
    // ...
    Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("listOfValues", nameRecordIDs);
    namedparameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, namedParameters,new MyMapper());`