# JdbcTemplate IN Clause for String elements

Tags: java, jdbc, collections, jdbctemplate

Am using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` for where Clause elements and one of them seems to be `List<String>`.  `JdbcTemplate` replaces them ?,?,?...(list size) but for a IN clause with `List<String>` it has to be '?','?'....

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There a few other similar questions out there which might have helpful answers for you:

[How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

To make this style of query work on my end, I have to switch from plain old JDBCTemplate to [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate).

Here is some example code:

```
String query = "select * from table where columnName in (:listOfValues)";
List<String> nameRecordIDs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
// ...
// add values to collection, then
// ...
Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("listOfValues", nameRecordIDs);
namedparameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, namedParameters,new MyMapper());
```