# SELECT IN clause in JDBCTemplates is not working

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I am tying to follow other example like this [How to use SELECT IN clause in JDBCTemplates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504592/how-to-use-select-in-clause-in-jdbctemplates) to use in clause in my query, but I am getting this error from queryForInt:

```
The method queryForInt(String, Object[]) in the type JdbcTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, Map)
```

This is my code:

```
    List groupList = getGroupsForUser(username);


    List<String> groupPara = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    for (Iterator groups = groupList.iterator(); groups.hasNext();) {
        Group g = (Group) groups.next();
        groupPara.add(g.getGroupName());
    }
    Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("listOfValues", groupPara);

    int groupPermissions = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt( "SELECT MAX(roleid) FROM groupaccess "
            + "WHERE inode = '"+inode.getId()+"' AND groupname in (:listOfValues)", namedParameters);

    return groupPermissions;
```

I got it to work by doing this, although is not very elegant:

```
List groupList = getGroupsForUser(username);
String groupPara = ("(");
Object[] params = new Object[groupList.size()+1];
params[0]=inode.getId();
int index = 1;
for (Iterator groups = groupList.iterator(); groups.hasNext();) {
    Group g = (Group) groups.next();
    params[index]=g.getGroupName();
    index++;
    groupPara += " ? ,";
}
groupPara = groupPara.substring(0, groupPara.length() - 1);
groupPara+=")";

int groupPermissions = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt( "SELECT MAX(roleid) FROM groupaccess "
        + "WHERE inode = ? AND groupname in "+groupPara, params);

return groupPermissions;
```

Comment: It clearly states that it expects `array` and not `Map` as the 2nd parameter.  So, what is your question?

Comment: my question is how am I suppose to pass in a list as parameter? In every example I seen, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504592/how-to-use-select-in-clause-in-jdbctemplates, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489138/jdbctemplate-in-clause-for-string-elements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504592/how-to-use-select-in-clause-in-jdbctemplates, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly, they passed a map object.

Answer (score 2):

[jdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForInt%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) does not have any method `queryForInt(String, Map)`. Instead you need to use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) . i.e:

```
Map<String,Object> namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("listOfValues", groupPara);

int groupPermissions = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForInt( "SELECT MAX(roleid) FROM groupaccess "
        + "WHERE inode = '"+inode.getId()+"' AND groupname in (:listOfValues)", namedParameters);
```

Or there is a workaround below:

```
Set<Integer> ids = groupPara;

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("listOfValues", ids);

List<Integer> foo = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt( "SELECT MAX(roleid) FROM groupaccess "
            + "WHERE inode = '"+inode.getId()+"' AND groupname in (:listOfValues)", getRowMapper(), namedParameters);
```

Comment: @PM77-1 Nope a type. Corrected it

Comment: @help you might want to google "jdbctemplate sql IN clause" for more examples :)

Comment: Why?  It's not my question. I'm just a bystander here.

Comment: @PM77-1 Oops sorry. mistake again

Comment: Still doesnt work for me. From here, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html, it seems no function for jdbcTemplate take MapSqlParameterSource  as parameter

Comment: Yes that is what I mentioned. You need to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for that