# Convert string to List<Long>

Tags: java

I have a string with comma separated value that I am getting direclty from database. Now I want to pass that entire string to another query but the datatype required is long and i want to use in clause to get this done.

```
str1 = [123,456,789];
```

Is there any direct way to do it instead of looping.

Comment: To my knowledge the only method is looping. I would store them in a LinkedList for O(N*M) where M is the length of each number (cost for converting string to long) and N is the number of elements

Comment: Can you show the queries you're attempted to run? What RDBMS is this?

Comment: When you say "comma separated value", are you talking about `.csv` file format, or numbers written for human consumption with a convention of commas between every group of 3 digits?

Comment: @user2986404 If you are asking about limit of characers with IN clause: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach

Comment: or if you could use jdbctemplate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<Long> longs = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(Splitter.on(',').split("1,2,3"), new Function<String, Long>() {
    public Long apply(final String in) {
        return in == null ? null : Longs.tryParse(in);
    }
}));
```

EDIT:

With a `List<String>` (`stringList`) as input:

```
List<Long> longs = Lists.newArrayList(Lists.transform(stringList, new Function<String, Long>() {
    public Long apply(final String in) {
        return in == null ? null : Longs.tryParse(in);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Hi Robin, this is giving me numberFormatException when I am passing the string. Actaully its List<String> that I changed to String from toString() method. Or is there a way I can directlt use thie List<String> to change to List<Long>?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Lambda functions of Java 8 to achieve this without looping

```
    String string = "1, 2, 3, 4";
    List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(string.split(",")).stream().map(s -> Long.parseLong(s.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: A slightly improved version: Stream.of(input.split(",")).map(s -> Long.parseLong(s.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 9):

A little shorter than virag's answer, as it skips asList() and doesn't do a string trim.

```
List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).map(s -> Long.parseLong(s.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you can do this without looping. Here is a sample workaround:

```
String str = "[123,456,789]";


Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();

 while (matcher.find()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group());
list.add(Long.parseLong(matcher.group())); // Add the value to the list
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use StringTokenizer and add split tokens to a list with a while loop.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1,2,3", ",");
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
     list.add(Long.valueOf(st.nextToken()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to get long value from a string

if str1="123,456,789"

```
 Long x=Long.parseLong(str1.replace(",",""));
```

and,

if str1="[123,456,789]"

```
Long x=Long.parseLong(str1.replace(",|\\[|\\]",""));
```

Comment: Yes, if it is used for the whole string, but not if it is used for a valid long.

Comment: @RobinGreen the question is about a string that contains `,` and not how to parse a long

Answer (score 0):

Use String.replace
assuming str1 contains "[123,123,123]"

```
str1 = str1.replace(",|\\[|\\]",""); //should replace commas and brackets with nothing;
```

then you should be able to do

```
Long myLong =  Long.parseLong(str1);
```

Comment: I am assuming the questioner means comma separated value in the sense of `.csv` file format, not in the sense of a number written for human consumption with commas between every 3 digits, but you could be right!