# JDBCTemplate query use arguments many times

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbctemplate

In JDBCTemplate, I'm calling

```
public <T> List<T> query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException {
            return query(sql, args, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<T>(rowMapper));
        }
```

with

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(usersByUsernameQuery, new String[] {username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>()
```

My problem is I only have access to the *usersByUsernameQuery* argument, and I want to use the 'username' variable twice in it. For example:

```
usersByUsernameQuery = "Select * from ... ... where someColumn=? or anotherColumn=?"
```

Since I'm only passing a string array with one element (username), how should I build my query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the same argument twice in the jdbcTemplate..

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(usersByUsernameQuery, new String[] {username, username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>()
```

This is completely valid and working.

Alternatively, you can go through the following thread if you can use a different variation of jdbcTemplate.query

[How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

Comment: yes, but the problem is I cant modify that line :P (compiled superclass)

overriding things will clutter/duplicate too much of the code

Comment: Thank you So Much for saving my project!