# How to do IN() and WHERE=? SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

This is an extension of [How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

I wish to modify the query to be:

```
"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name=? and value IN (:ids)"
```

how can I modify the given code to support the name=? parameter

```
Set<Integer> ids = ...;

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", ids);

List<Foo> foo = getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a IN (:ids)",
     getRowMapper(), parameters);
```

Comment: Why not to use 'name' as named parameter too? name=:name

Comment: Use a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` instead of a `JdbcTemplate` .

Answer (score 1):

I was successful using both comments.

I will post the code below for those who may find this question later:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name=:name and value IN (:ids)";

Set<Integer> ids = ...;
String name = "John";

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", ids);
parameters.addValue("name",name);

List<Foo> foo = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sql, parameters, getRowMapper());
```