# How do I return a list of objects from an sql query using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, spring

If my SQL is:

```
select id, name, age from my_table where id in (...)
```

(we want to pass in the *in* values as arguments).

We have a our ID values

```
 List<Integer> = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(111,222,333));
```

A person object

```
public class Person
{
    private int id;
    private int age;
    private String name;
    //getters setters, constructors
}
```

Now I want to use the jdbcTemplate to execute the SQL such that I get a `List<Person>` returned.

I've already created a method that will convert the sql string into

```
select id, name, age from my_table where id in (?,?,?)
```

if that helps.

Looking at the [JdbcTemplate javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) it looks like I'd want to use one of the `queryForList` methods.

Comment: Possible answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use one of `queryForList` method.

Probably you will need this method:

`queryForList(java.lang.String sql, java.lang.Class<T> elementType, java.lang.Object... args)`

Answer (score 0):

Following method gives you the list of objects:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(T.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a RowMapper of Person class and use below code to get the list of objects.

```
    String SQL = "select * from my_table";
    List<Person> persons = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL,
            new PersonMapper());
    return persons;
```