# how to pass list parameter in IN clause using jdbcTemplate

Tags: mysql, jdbctemplate

I want to pass list values in IN clause using jdbcTemplate in mysql query. Like below,

```
 List<Long> listId= new ArrayList<>();
 listId.add(1234L);
 listId.add(1235L);
 listId.add(1236L);

 String type ="A";
 List<BojoClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
 String sql="select column1,column2  from table where columName in(?)"
 result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{listId}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<BojoClass>(BojoClass.class));
```

How to achieve this in best way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` may help for you.

For your sample, try this please:)

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = ...

List<Long> listId= new ArrayList<>();
listId.add(1234L);
listId.add(1235L);
listId.add(1236L);

String sql="select column1,column2  from table where columName in(:ids)";
List<BojoClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
Map idsMap = Collections.singletonMap("ids", listId);
result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, idsMap, ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(BojoClass.class));
```

**Edited:**

If you can get `DataSource`, you can just init a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` object by its constructor like:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
```

Comment: I am getting compile time excetion : "no suitable method found for query(String,Map,ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper<BojoClass>)"

Comment: Is your jdbcTemplate type `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`?

Comment: No. how to make it?

Comment: `SimpleJdbcTemplate` or `JdbcTemplate`?

Comment: please check my updated question.

Comment: @Blank - how do you manipulate above to deal with the list of 10k records.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your list with `StringUtils.join(paramListForInClause, ",");` to generate the string you need

Comment: Like people said in another topic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788183/3800377.  "listeParamsForInClause wont be escaped and makes you vulnerable to SQL injection."