# Supply a list of column values with wildcards, to a sql query

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g

Using Java 8 , Oracle 11g and Spring Boot, we normally run a SQL select something like:

```
String sqlQuery="select col1,col2 from myTable where col1 = :colValue";
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("colValue", "xxx");
// Then run the query :
List<MyClass>= jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery,parameters,(rs, rowNum) -> new MyClass
      (rs.getString("col1"),rs.getString("col2"))  );
```

It is also possible to supply a  List of col1 values

```
String sqlQuery="select col1,col2 from myTable where col1 in ( :colList) ";
Map<String, List<String>> parameters = new HashMap<String, List<String>();
List<String> myColList= Arrays.asList("xxx", "yyy");
parameters.put("colList", myColList );
```

But what if we want to include SQL wildcards in the column values:

```
String sqlQuery="select col1,col2 from myTable where col1 like ( :colList) ";
List<String> myColList= Arrays.asList("%xxx%", "yyy%");
```

We can't mix LIKE and IN  constructs in a where clauses, so is there any other way of doing it? I know I can dynamically construct my own where clause but I'm trying to avoid that. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass list parameter in IN clause using jdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518094/how-to-pass-list-parameter-in-in-clause-using-jdbctemplate)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes it does, but I had oversimplified my original question. I've updated the question to include the real problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MapSqlParameterSource`

```
Set<Integer> myColList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("xxx", "yyy"));
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("colList", myColList);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I over simplified my original question, sorry. I've updated it to include the real problem

Comment: @DS. You can't do `like` query like `In` query. You have to use same column multiple times with `OR` condition

Comment: yes, but can you assign the values to the OR using MapSqlParameterSource  or similar

Comment: I don't think so, you have to manually construct where condition