# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type for update query with In clause in jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am trying to update the Oracle table row using jdbcTemplate as follows

```
String sql = "update EVENTS set status = null where TEMP_ID IN (select TEMP_ID from EVENTS where STATUS = 'COMPLETE' and EXCHANGE_ID IN (?)   )";    
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<Long> longValues = new ArrayList<Long>();
longValues.add(1);
longValues.add(2);
paramMap.put("EXCHANGE_ID", longValues);
int rowsAffected = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,paramMap,Long.class);
```

where EXCHANGE_ID is a column in EVENTS table with data type NUMBER(6,0).

When I try to run the above program it is throwing an exception as follows

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [update
>   EVENTS set status = null where TEMP_ID IN (select TEMP_ID from EVENTS
>   where STATUS = 'COMPLETE' and EXCHANGE_ID= ?   )]; SQL state [99999];
>   error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

**Edit :** Number of Parameters in In clause are not fixed. so number of Parameters can be 2 ,3 depending upon the user.

for simplicity I have added following lines in code

```
longValues.add(1);
longValues.add(2);
```

In reality I am receiving Parameters from the form. I have just added part of code in my question.

Due to some constraints I can only use ? at my Parameter place in my sql query not :EXCHANGE_ID

Comment: My guess is that you can't bind a list the way you are doing it.

Comment: How to do it then?

Comment: Are the number of list elements fixed/known?

Comment: I am accepting list elements from form but for simplicity I had added in my code like this longValues.add(1);
longValues.add(2);

Comment: I ask this because you may just use a fixed number of placeholders, e.g. `WHERE IN (?, ?)`

Comment: No number of list elements are not fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

Answer (score 1):

Updated: You need to use **:EXCHANGE_ID** in the SQL sentence:

```
final String sql = "update EVENTS set status = null where TEMP_ID IN (select TEMP_ID from EVENTS where STATUS = 'COMPLETE' and EXCHANGE_ID = :EXCHANGE_ID)";

final MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.put("EXCHANGE_ID", Long.valueOf(1));

int rowsAffected = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params);
```

Comment: EXCHANGE_ID is just an ID or a list? Beacuse in your updated query you are using a equals operation and passing a list.

Comment: EXCHANGE_ID is just an ID

Comment: See my updated answer. Please, let me know if it works ;)

Comment: see my updated query again . problem is number of parameters in In clause are not fixed.

Comment: @PawanPatil if you are restricted to use `?` you must dynamically generate the required number of the `?` according to the number of the values in the list. Only using [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) allows you to expand the parameter to the required number of placeholders.