# SQL queries with 'IN' in Java or Groovy

Tags: java, mysql, groovy

I have written a SQL query:

```sql
select sum(amount) as totalAmount 
from employee_account 
where id = 29967 
and repayment_status in ("MARKEDPAID", "PAID", "PENDING", "OVERDUE");
```

This query is working fine in MySQL console. I have to execute this query in Java using

```java
String query = ""
int id = 123
Connection connection = // connection code 
Statement statement = connection.createStatement()
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)
```

I write the

```
query = "select sum(amount) as totalAmount from employee_account where id = ${id} and repayment_status in ()"
```

How do I pass `"MARKEDPAID", "PAID", "PENDING", "OVERDUE"` in above String query?

Comment: By single quotes?

Comment: in ('MARKEDPAID', 'PAID', 'PENDING', 'OVERDUE') is this is correct?
@AnkitSharma

Comment: Yeah MySQL is fine with single or double any quotes as long as you are consistent

Comment: not worked i have to execute through java code

Comment: oh ok, maybe someone else can help

Comment: How are you executing the statement from java?

Comment: @Prog_G I tried multiples way like for ex-
List<String> strings = ["PAID","PENDING"]
and then in query i pass this list  but nothing works

Comment: String concat works?

Comment: why there are 2 language tags? do you need `java` or `groovy`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectively

Comment: Thanks Guys I figured out how to implement this
Thanks for your time @LizhiLiu

Comment: @injecteer No, i do it with my own logic

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not use string interpolation for adding values into a query string, use JDBC parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String status = "\'OVERDUE\',\'PAID\',\'PENDING\',\'MARKEDPAID\'"
String query = "select sum(amount) as totalAmount from employee_account where id = ${id} and repayment_status in (${status})"
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not use string interpolation for adding values into a query string, use JDBC parameters (the use of `${status}` is safe in **this** case, but `${id}` is not!).